# Style the first <td> column of a table differently

Tags: css, css-selectors, padding

If I have a `table` with two columns, how do I specify a `padding` or any other css so that it is applied just for the first column of `<td>`s. Also how do I style an ***n-th*** column similarly?

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/firstchild.html - http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/nthchild.html

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You could use the [n-th child selector](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

to target the nth element you could then use:

```
td:nth-child(n) {  
  /* your stuff here */
}
```

(where `n` starts at 1)

Comment: Suggest td:first-child over this mostly because it has more support for older IE versions. If browser support isn't an issue nth-child is a powerful selector to begin using.

Comment: Yes, for the first element, `first-child` is better. But OP asked for both :)

Comment: And `n` start with 1, not with 0.

Comment: But if the first `td` of previous `tr` has a rowspan greater than 1, `first-child` will mis-select a 2nd-column `td`. Any trick to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

If you've to support IE7, a more compatible solution is:

```
/* only the cells with no cell before (aka the first one) */
td {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
/* only the cells with at least one cell before (aka all except the first one) */
td + td {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Also works fine with `li`; general sibling selector `~` may be more suitable with mixed elements like a heading h1 followed by paragraphs AND a subheading and then again other paragraphs.

Comment: Simple, easy to read and works a treat!

Comment: This actually worked for me, where nth-child and first-child did not (perhaps due to cascading rules? *shrug*)

Answer (score 13):

The **:nth-child()** and **:nth-of-type()** pseudo-classes allows you to select elements with a formula.

The syntax is **:nth-child(an+b)**, where you replace a and b by numbers of your choice.

For instance, :nth-child(3n+1) selects the 1st, 4th, 7th etc. child.

```
td:nth-child(3n+1) {  
  /* your stuff here */
}
```

**:nth-of-type()** works the same, except that it only considers element of the given type ( in the example).

For more information about nth-child
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 5):

This should help. Its CSS3 :first-child where you should say that the first `tr` of the table you would like to style. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Comment: Also if you would like to only style the first `tr` of a specific table you could put `.tableclass tr:first-child` or `#tableid tr:first-child`

Comment: `:first-child` isn't new to CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

To select the first column of a table you can use this syntax

```
tr td:nth-child(1n + 2){
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```